# Does a UK Voucher Code used on an Australian Account download the UK game?

Tags: psn

When I got Child of Light from a UK Store it came with a Voucher Code. when I used it on my Australian PSN Account it downloaded just fine however I know the game was also on the Australian Store.

Monster Monpiece isn't available in Australia (because our ratings board are a bunch of retards) however I was thinking of something.

**If I got a PSN Voucher Code for Monster Monpiece from another country, would it fail because there is no Australian version to download, or would it download the UK Version?**

Also if the latter would happen, would the UK Download then be tied to my Australian PSN account, so in the case of a Vita, I wouldn't need to screw around with different PSN Accounts?